# Best place to change CurrentCultureUI with URL approach?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

What I want to accomplish is let the user change it through a nice couple of flags in the Web application. Where is the best place to put the code to let the user change the current thread? And the best way to implement the code?

This is what I have so far.

I have a localized site. I chose to have the URL route specifying the language like this:

```
http://localhost:59293/es/Reports/Performance
http://localhost:59293/en/Reports/Performance
```

As you can see "us" and "es" are the UI languages. I followed the route + filter strategy:

```
  public class InternationalizationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        var language = (string)filterContext.RouteData.Values["language"] ?? "en";
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(string.Format("{0}", language));
    }
}
```

Then I register this Action Filter in Global.Asax like this:

```
        protected void Application_Start()
    {

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new InternationalizationAttribute());
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        //Creo los mappings de entidades.
        AutoMapperHelper.Configure();

    }
```

Now the routes:

```
     routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DefaultLocalizedLanguage",
        url: "{language}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional, language = "en" });
```

So far so good. If I change my URL to the specified language changing the URL "es" to "en" I can see my app in those languages.

Now how to implement the Thread cultureUI change?

Comment: @m.casey I was reading a lot of questions in SO even that. But I want to know if this is the right approach based on my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong - isn't the change a matter of linking to the correct url?

So you link to (pseudo) @String.Join("es", Request.Url.Segments.Skip(1)) ??

Also you may wanna let the language be optional, and then use Request Accept-Language for fallback.

Previously I've also used referrer to keep the user in correct language context.

Comment: modec. Thanks for replying. That is what Im asking. I have this base set up, now I want to know the best way to let user change cultureUI. After that Im planning to keep a cookie to remember the option, but since now I have a filter Im asking for best practices.